# How to connect storyboard to viewcontroller

Tags: interface-builder, ios7, xcode5

In the new xcode 5 how do in interface builder you use to have a drop down menu there to connect your storyboard viewcontrollers to your classes how is this done now?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, it's still there. Here are the steps to assign a custom view controller class to your view controller:

1. Choose your view controller in the list of scenes on the left side.

[image: Choose view controller screenshot]

2. Choose the Identify Inspector on the right side.
3. Choose the custom view controller class from the Class list.

[image: Choose custom view controller class screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

1、manual creating a Cocoa Class to the project

2、open the story board, **draw a view controller from tool box** to the storyborad

3、click the controller you draw into the storyboard, and specify the 'Customer Class' to the class you create in step 1

4、if you use XIB, nibName could be the controller name, else if you use StoryBoard, you need set a storyboard id for your controller in your storyboard panel, and you can use the id and the storyboard in your superController when you want to new a controller

```
// XIB
var viewController = UIViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
// StoryBoard
var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "The-Storyboard-ID-You-Set") as! ViewController
```