# How to connect ViewController.swift to ViewController in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I made a new view controller in Storyboard and made a new .Swift file that inherits `UIViewController`. However, my `viewDidLoad()` is not being called.

What do I need to do to connect my view controller in my story board to my .swift code so `viewDidLoad()` is called?

I see there's this: [How to connect storyboard to viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370208/how-to-connect-storyboard-to-viewcontroller)

However, in a default project, FirstViewController(storyboard) doesn't have FirstViewController in that box, it is empty, yet `viewDidLoad()` is still called. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: The link provided it’s correct, you just choose in the Class field the right Swift file;

Answer (score 120, accepted):

1. Choose your ViewController in the storyboard or scene list (mine is called `Circuit`).
2. Click on the `Identity Inspector` on the right
3. Select `Custom Class > Class > Type name of your swift file`.

DONE :)

[image: Here are these two steps on image (ugly i know)]

Comment: What if the project is a mix of `Obj-C` & `Swift` Classes, and there are `Obj-C` ViewController Classes and `Swift` ViewController Classes?

Comment: remarkable my xcode ui has all 4 buttons other than the one displayed. Just great.

Answer (score 8):

You have your `ViewControler` created with some Objects in it (`UILabel`, `UIButton`, `UIImage`...)

[image]

1 - You need to link your ViewControler in your story board to your `ViewController.swift` , to do this follow the pictures

[image]

2 - In the class filed put the name of the ViewController class. With that you just linked your storyBoard view controller to your `viewController.swift` class

> Class = `ViewController.swift`

[image]

3 - Now you need to cretae the variables you want to asign(UILabel, UIButton ... that you have in your storyboard): in this example:

```
class MovieDetailViewController: UIViewController, DetailView {
    
    var presenter: MovieDetailPresenter!
    var movie: Movie?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMovieYear: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMovieTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMovieRating: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMovieOverview: UILabel! 
}
```

4 - To link the UILabel in the story board to your UILabel variable or your UIButton in your story board to your UIButton var, follow the next images

First select the view controller in the storyboard

[image]

Second select the parragraf icon in the right up corner ands clicked 'Assistant', it will open a screen of your `ViewControler.swift`

[image]
[image]

Now you just need to  drag the variable to the corresponding object and you will be done.[image]

**Remember to do this with all variables, you will need to create a variable for each object you have in the storyboard**

Comment: awesome explaination

Answer (score 1):

**Connect storyboard and view controller**

You should set `ViewController in` Class` field

[image]