# Instantiating Initial View Controller Provides Nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

For my tab bar controller, I want a transition for 4/5 tabs. The fifth tab i was able to successfully perform a different transition, but trying to add it to the other view controllers caused a crash.

> Action Storyboard: This storyboard contains my tab bar controller, and my camera view controller. The transition for this view controller is the only one that works. When i try to transition different tabs that are not in the tab bar controllers storyboard, it crashes
>
> [image: Storyboard that contains tab bar controller]

This is the storyboard with the problem

> For example, I want to provide a different transition for the view controller in this storyboard. However, i get the error:
> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value
> [image: Home Storyboard]

This is my code:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if let restoreID = viewController.restorationIdentifier {
        if restoreID == "NavigationCamera" {
        // This is the transition that works
            if let nav = tabBarController.viewControllers![tabBarController.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
                print("Nav is allowed")
                let newVC = tabBarController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CameraView")
                let transition = CATransition()
                transition.duration = 0.25
                transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
                transition.type = kCATransitionPush
                transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
                nav.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
                nav.pushViewController(newVC!, animated: false)
                return false
            }
        } else {
            if let otherNav = tabBarController.viewControllers![tabBarController.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
                print("Other nav is allowed")
                let vcID = restoreID + "View"
                print(vcID)
                let myVC = otherNav.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
                let otherTransition = CATransition()
                otherTransition.duration = 0.25
                otherTransition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
                otherTransition.type = kCATransitionPush
                otherTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFade
                otherNav.view.layer.add(otherTransition, forKey: nil)
                // This is where the error occurs and crashes
                otherNav.pushViewController(myVC!, animated: false)
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Once again the error i get is:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: otherNav.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() is returning nil and then you are using myVC! on nil value

Comment: I was having the same issue - turns out I didn't have a link to a Controller - followed the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311000/how-to-connect-viewcontroller-swift-to-viewcontroller-in-storyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: <other storyboard>, bundle: nil)
let myVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: <your navigation controler>)
```

Comment: is the <other storyboard> the name of my storyboard file? e.g. "Home.storyboard"

Comment: without extension for example: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)