# AppDelegate problem when i close Onboarding and run application for second time

Tags: swift, appdelegate, uipagecontrol

I make onboarding with UIPageViewController its work but when I run the App for Second time the Xib not working

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //////OnBoarding
        let lunchbefor = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "haslunched")
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let lunchstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "onboarding", bundle: nil)
        let mainstoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        var vc: UIViewController
        if lunchbefor{
            window?.rootViewController = MainVC()
            vc = mainstoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!

        }else{
            vc = lunchstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "start")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "haslunched")
        if lunchbefor == false{

            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }else{
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            window?.rootViewController = MainVC()

        }

        return true
    }
```

error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

on this line:

```swift
vc = mainstoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: crash happens @sazzad-hissain-khan

Comment: could you provide an error message that appears?

Comment: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on this line :             vc = mainstoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instantiating Initial View Controller Provides Nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588214/instantiating-initial-view-controller-provides-nil)

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer 
I did this:

```
  var vc: UIViewController

    if lunchbefor{
        window?.rootViewController = MainVC()
       // vc = mainstoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        vc =  MainVC()

    }else{
        vc = lunchstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "start")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `instantiateInitialViewController` you need to select `Is Initial View Controller` in a storyboard (red arrow on the screen), and you will see an indicator that the view controller is the initial one (green arrow)

[image: Selecting a <code>Is Initial View Controller</code>]

Also, it is a good idea not to use force unwrap (`!`) as it will crash your app when a variable is `nil`.