# WebKit View not connecting to ViewController (Control + Drag)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try and control, click and drag the WebKit View from my main.Storyboard it just has the blue line but no connection options. I tried it on my UIViewController.h and it gave me connection options. Is this a bug? If so how can I fix it? [This is the blue line I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvJiH.png)

Comment: Make sure that the View Controller in the Storyboard is of the ViewController's type you want to connect to. (See Identitiy inspector)

Comment: Which type is it that I want to connect to? There are a lot of them and it's set on "Default - Swift Source"

Comment: check if you set the className for that UIViewController

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, Md Rashed Pervez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you imported webkit module

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
```

**Then Connect out let**
works for me!

[image: Ctrl+Click and drag to view controller]

[image: Release click where ever in side view controller when you see "Insert outlet message with collection line"]

Or try reverse like screen short. First manually write 
        @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

then click drag from code to Webview 
[image: Write IBOutlet manually]

Comment: I had not, however it still did not fix my problem.

Comment: Then try reverse. Type "@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!" manually in swift file and click drag from un connected point of IBOutlet in code to Webview.

Comment: I tried that but it's giving me the same connecting blue line with no option to connect it. And If I try to just click the plus button on New Referencing Outlet, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please toggle Manual to Automatic in your assistant editor. and check wether your storyboard view controller connected to right class!!

Comment: How do I know if they're connected to the right class? I am new to Xcode, sorry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311000/how-to-connect-viewcontroller-swift-to-viewcontroller-in-storyboard

Comment: Thank you! I feel so dumb right now. I can't believe it was that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your view controller containing the WebKit have so many IBOutlets and IBActions?

Is your Storyboard UIViewController correctly connected to it's corresponding UIViewController class? It's most likely this, if it isn't it might simply be a bug, try cleaning the project, closing it and reopening.

Select your view controller in storyboard and then [image]

Comment: I had so many IBOutlets and IBActions because this is a work in progress app. I had tried to make something harder than what it really was.
I cleaned it up however it did not fix my problem.

Comment: Did you do what we have all told you to do and give the storyboard its class?

Comment: I didn't understand how to do that, but now I do understand what that is. Thank you for your help.