# Why does the Breakfast Finder sample code result in a blank screen after adding it to a new xcodeproj file?

Tags: swift, xcode, avcapturesession, ios15

**Goal**

I am trying to apply the object detection functionality of the [Breakfast Finder sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture) to my app. When I add my personal model to the Breakfast Finder sample code and run it, it detects my objects and presents labels just fine.

**Problem**

When I attempt to add the sample code to a test app (new xcodeproj file), I can't get the live camera feed. I just get the security pop-up and a blank screen.

**What I did to get the problem**

1. Copy over the `ViewController` and `ViewObjectRecognitionViewController` swift files
2. Link the Preview View referencing outlet to the `@IBOutlet` in the `ViewController` - line 17
3. Add the mlmodel file (from the sample code, not my mlmodel file)
4. Add the `NSCameraUsageDescription` to the Info file (with a value).

On another attempt, I tried just copying all the files (swift, plist, mlmodel, etc.) over from the sample code and troubleshooting connection issues, but got the same problem.

**Final Thoughts**

Why does the Breakfast Finder sample code result in a blank screen after adding it to a new xcodeproj file? I have never dealt with live camera feed so I might have overlooked a simple problem. I have an iPhone XR running on ios15. You can find a link to the sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture) or google Breakfast Finder.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you configure your permissions in your `.plist`? [This might be helpful](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios).

Comment: @Yrb Thank you! I have done the "Configure Your App's Info.plist File" section in the link you shared. I think the other sections were not relevant because they were not used in the Breakfast Finder sample code. I have tried 1) adding only NSCameraUsageDescription and 2) copying over the whole .plist file from the sample code to the new .xcodeproj file. Neither method activates live camera feed in the new .xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually noticed that the view controller in the storyboard was actually VisionObjectRecognitionViewController. So I replaced the view controller by doing the following:

1. Selected the View Controller in the document outline in main.storyboard
2. Selected the identity inspector on the top right side of the screen
3. Changed the class to VisionObjectRecognitionViewController (you need to add the VisionObjectRecognitionViewController.swift file to your project before doing this step)

And, that fixed it! I could not only see the live video feed, but also see my model detecting objects! Thank you @Iker Solozabal for providing [similar steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311000/how-to-connect-viewcontroller-swift-to-viewcontroller-in-storyboard) on another question.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and helpful best practices tip! I opted for adapting the solution to my question. Please let me know if there are any problems with my question/solution! Two more thoughts - 1) I opted for adaptation because I believe that if someone else was in my shoes, they would easily find my question and would need to see my question and answer to get to the solution (they wouldn't know that Iker Solozabal's answer was the solution) and 2) Screenshots would have been very helpful in my solution but I don't have enough reputation (need 10).