# How to know the design file assigned to view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm launching a view controller in my app with this code :

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

However I don't know what design file my viewcontroller use to add a simple label to it. I don't know if it uses any design file(story board). I have story board file and I have assigned its class to my controller but does the above code launch the controller with the story board?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myViewController` does not connect to any xib file(design file)

You could connect your design file using this construct method of `UIViewController`.

> ```
> - (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
> ```

For example:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Your_Design_File_Name" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks , is it also doable with story boards?

Comment: If you use storyboard, here is a link that might help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370208/how-to-connect-storyboard-to-viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks , and just initing the viewcontroller will be enough to launch it with story board design?

Comment: No,you don't have to create that view controller by code if you use storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I'll appreciate if you give me a snippet on how to launch a story board

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Your_Storyboard_Name" bundle:nil]; // initialize your storyboard    UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController]; // get initial view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:initViewController animated:YES];  initial view controller is your storyboard's entry point view controller.

Comment: You can read more on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536689/xcode-4-5-how-to-pick-storyboards-at-launch