# Connect UITableViewCell content to outlet in code

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView with a UITableViewCell with a textview and imageview inside it

In swift file I have defined

```
class NotificationCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var notificationAvatarImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var notificationText: UITextView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    notificationAvatarImage.clipsToBounds = true
    notificationAvatarImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
}
```

I am unable to connect the imageView & textview in storyboard to IBOutlet notificationAvatarImage ... in NotificationCell. How do I do this?

Iam loading the table as

```
guard let notificationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? NotificationCell else {
        fatalError("Error getting cell")
}
```

Comment: Hello,Refer this link:-https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Comment: @anoop You should assign UITableViewCell class with your class NotificationCell in storyboard

Comment: is there any error while connecting IBOutlet or what difficulty you are facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect storyboard to viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370208/how-to-connect-storyboard-to-viewcontroller)

Comment: @VDPurohit thanks man that helped. I hadnt made NotifciationCell the class for my Cell in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate of tableview to load the tableviewcell.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! NotificationCell
    return cell
}
```

**Using Storyboard**

Now create the UITableViewCell in your storyboard and set the `Class` of that UITableViewCell to `NotificationCell` and then right click on your imageview and textview of the tableviewcell in storyboard and assign it to the `@IBOutlet` of `NotificationCell` class you wrote in Swift